# Why is the last line of the file always read twice with my mips assembly code?

Tags: assembly, mips

I have the following simple function in my assembly code:

```
.data
file:   .asciiz "file"
buffer: .space  4096

.text
main:



# READ FILE
li $v0, 13
la $a0, file
li $a1, 0
li $a2, 0
syscall

# SAVE FD
move $t1, $v0

# READ TO BUFFER
li $v0, 14
move $a0, $t1
la $a1, buffer
li $a2, 4096
syscall

move $t0, $v0

# PRINT TEXT
li $v0, 4
move $a0, $a1
syscall

# CLOSE FILE
li $v0, 16
move $a0, $t1 # fd
syscall

li $v0, 10
syscall
move $v0, $t0
```

Which works, but not the way I want it to. It reads and prints everything, but the last line of the file is twice, while the second last line isnt even complete, the first few chars are missing and I dont understand why. I mean yes, adjusting the Buffer of 4096 would probably help but I dont want to adjust it everytime I want to read another file. Whats wrong with the code and what do I have to change or add? I would appreciate any kind of help

Comment: What is `mail`?

Comment: My bad, should be "file", changed now

Comment: Does the function to read return the number of bytes read? Does the function to print text require null termination? You need to check return values. You may need a loop to read and print repeatedly until less than the requested number of bytes are read indicating there is nothing left.

Comment: Yes, it reads exactly the amount of characters thats in the file. And I hear "null termination" for the first time now. Is a loop the only way I can make this work?

Comment: I just tried adjusting the Buffer to 1058, which is exactly the amount of characters in the file, but that didnt work either. It just cuts even more chars from the end of the file and repeats the last line again. No matter what I do, it doesnt work...

Comment: Sounds like perhaps a buffered input issue.  Try closing the file before printing as this may flush the buffer for you.  It's a bit of a long shot, but it may work.  Also confirm that your read function is allowed to be passed a size that is greater than the file length.

Comment: Okay, after setting the first byte after the input in the buffer to zero, it works. "Null Termination" was the problem here. Thanks alot!